# Maui-blazor gradient splash screen

Tags: c#, blazor, maui

Is it possible to set a gradient splash screen?
[In example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/splashscreen?tabs=android)

`<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Images\splashscreen.svg" Color="#512BD4" />`

i want the background to be a gradient and have a word on it

Tried:

- `<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\gradientWithWord.svg" />` i tried set image, but size is set incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set [BaseSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/splashscreen?tabs=android) on MauiSplashScreen  .

> The value of the `BaseSize` attribute represents the baseline density of the splash screen, and is effectively the 1.0 scale factor for the splash screen from which all other density sizes are derived.

If we don't specify a `BaseSize` for a bitmap-based splash screen, the image isn't resized.

If we don't specify a `BaseSize` value for a vector-based splash screen, the dimensions specified in the SVG are assumed to be the base size.

Try

```
<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Images\splashscreen.svg" BaseSize="128,128" />
```